# Trouble Sending Emails with PHP Using PHPMailer: Getting 'Cannot Send Mail' Error

Tags: php, email, visual-studio-code, phpmailer

I'm encountering an issue while trying to send emails using PHP's PHPMailer library. I'm getting an error that says 'Cannot Send Mail.' and I've tried different ways to send mail even I got helped from ChatGpt but I could not. I've followed the documentation and my code looks like this:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer-master/PHPMailer.php';
require __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer-master/Exception.php';
require __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer-master/SMTP.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    try {
        // SMTP configuration
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'example@gamil.com';
        $mail->Password = 'mypassword'; // Replace with your Gmail password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;

        // Sender and recipient details
        $mail->setFrom('example@gmail.com', 'Ahmed Maajid');
        $mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com'); // Set your Gmail address as both sender and recipient

        // Email content
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        $mail->Subject = 'New submission from your website';
        $mail->Body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email;

        $mail->send();
        echo 'Email sent successfully!';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Oops! There was a problem: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What happened when you did [what the documentation tells you to do](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) to diagnose issues like this?

Answer (score 1):

**You may recheck the following**

- Your gmail password isn't actually the password you use to sign in to your gmail account. If you're using Google's SMTP, it should be the password generated duration **App password** creating.
- If you're using localhost, you still need to be connected to the internet (if you're using SMTP)
- I hope you've modified the ... example fields with your own configuration.
- You may refer to the web for how set up Google SMTP for PHPMailer

**Bonus** Temporary enable the debug true so you can know more about the error

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = true;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Composer is the easiest way to get PHPMailer up and running. Just open your terminal and type: `composer require phpmailer/phpmailer`. Here's the code snippet to send an email:

```
require("./vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
require("./vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php");


// make all the setup to send email
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSmtp();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "your_email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "your_password";
$mail->setFrom("your_email@gmail.com");
// make email subject & body
$subject = "testing subject";
$messageBody = "testing message";
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $messageBody;
// send to
$sendTo = "recipient_email@example.com";
$mail->AddAddress($sendTo);
// send request
if($mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Email has been sent!';
} else {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: How is that different from what OP already has? What did you change to make it work?

Comment: In my case, my website was not having SSL certificate, so setting VERIFY_PEER to False is basically equivalent to disabling TLS altogether and connecting over plaintext HTTP which made it work for me.

Comment: Warning: require(PHPMailer-master\PHPMailer-master\PHPMailer.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory 

This error shows

Comment: I'm unable to directly verify file paths, but I can provide guidance to ensure accuracy if you have downloaded from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer:
```The path is typically PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php```